# How to undo multiple steps in a Tic-Tac-Toe game in C

Tags: c, function, tic-tac-toe, undo, revert

I want to program a version of the Tic-Tac-Toe game using C, in which we have 'n × n' board decided by the user, and the loser is decided by the first who get first 'n' X's or O's in a row or column etc..

One of the requirements is to let the players be able to undo multiple steps, that means to get back to the board status as it was a couple of steps ago by entering a negative odd number.

For example, if player 1 entered '-3' as the row index, the game needs to revert back how it was 3 steps before (in case there has already been 3 steps done within the game), show the board and give the turn to player 2.

Any idea how I would be able to make such a function or at least a tip how would I start programming it?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep an array of all moves that have been made.  To undo moves, simply go back through the array and clear the cells that were played.

Comment: @TomKarzes That means to create a new array for each step?

Comment: I think what he meant was create an array that can represent all steps, as each step is taken add the move to the array. Then to undo, you simply back up that number of moves erasing what was in each cell. You can probably do it with a 9-element array for tic-tac-toe and store either `1` or `0` for `x` and `o`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh I got you, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, the way undo is generally done is you have a simple struct that holds the info that describes a move, like *cell* and *X/O*. Then with each move you push the move onto a simple stack, and to undo, you just pop the last however many moves you like. You can do the same thing with a simple array-of-struct (or two arrays at it's most basic). Just something that will hold the "what and where" of each move.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yea I get you, basically in this case the board size has to be entered by the user while it'll always be 11×11 or less, so that's why I kind of found the making a new array for each step a bit excessive.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but seeing how you put it now and how undo generally done, I think I can think of a way to utilize that for this case or to make something based on the concept

Answer (score 0):

> idea how I would be able to make such a function or at least a tip how would I start programming it?

An alternative to *undoing* a step it to instead keep a history (linked list) of all actively.  Replay the list *sans* the last one to "undo".  Less efficient yet less complicated and less error prone to undo complicated steps - which may be present in more advanced games.  Sometimes, "backing up" is wrought with subtle complexities where the prior state is not truly fully restored.  Akin to [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178535/how-to-undo-multiple-steps-in-a-tic-tac-toe-game-in-c/56179641#comment98983385_56178535) [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178535/how-to-undo-multiple-steps-in-a-tic-tac-toe-game-in-c/56179641#comment98983489_56178535)

As a bonus, you have a game record.

---

Consider your game has events like:

- Default setup-up
- Select size `n`.
- Select X or O to go first
- **Make a move**
- Rotate view
- Save game
- Restore game
- Undo last command <-- now one can undo more than just the last "move"
- etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I fully understood your answer. Can you please elaborate a bit more? (This time while knowing I'm a beginner, started learning C alone 5 weeks ago..)

Comment: user11513173, "I don't think I fully understood" --> what parts do you understand?  So I do not have to elaborate the whole answer.  Your question had "Any idea how" and now it sound like you are looking for more than ideas, but code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would have a stack where you can put each new move and when you want to undo a move, you just pop it from the stack and do the reverse move on your game model.